# What is equivalent to PHP `include_path` in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

What is equivalent to [`include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in Node.js (or Deno)?

or at least is any way to specify the root folder of JS files so you can `require` files using a relative path to it instead of the current folder?

Comment: Not using `import { .. } from ''`?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at alias i believe.

In webpack we can achieve this.

PS: following from docs

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/'),
    },
  },
};
```

Now, instead of using relative paths when importing like so:

```
import Utility from '../../utilities/utility';
```

you can use the alias:

```
import Utility from 'Utilities/utility';
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

**OR**

You can also use modules like [modules-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) to achieve same objective.

**OR**

If you use babel -> https://github.com/timkendall/babel-plugin-base-path

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about that. Regarding Webpack,  It seems `roots` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveroots) is closer to what I asked. 

However, Webpack and node.js are not quite the same. My question is about Node.

Comment: Webpack is used to compile JavaScript modules. If that's complicated for you try option 2. In nodejs, the project path is in the dirname env variable. We almost never go further than that.